# DateTime in sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#, sharepoint, datetime, sharepoint-2007, datetime-format

I am fetching list date item in string variable then I want to insert it in SQL table, but in SQL the column type is DateTime. So I need to convert string to DateTime.

I am using below code:

```
DateTime strAllocatedOn; 
string[] format = { "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt" };
DateTime.TryParseExact(dt.Rows[j]["Created"].ToString(), format, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out strAllocatedOn);
```

But getting below error:

> An error occurred during the compilation of the requested file, or one
>   of its dependencies. Invalid expression term 'out'

Date format which I am receving is "10/3/2011 4:38:27 PM".

Comment: Beware, as DateTime format can change depending on users regional settings. But looking at the code i feel you do something not the right way. Does `dt.Rows[j]` really return a string or a DateTime? What does dt.Rows[j].GetType() return ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply..
Yes it is retunring the date I have checked it.

Comment: This is a compilation error saying that it got to an 'out' expression when it didn't make sense. The code you have pasted above looks fine. Are you sure it's not another part of the code that is causing the error?

Comment: @Ash what is the type of returned object? It is _possibly_ already a DateTime and why would you Convert to string and then back? Check what GetType() returns.

Answer (score 1):

The formats you're giving don't match the sample value you've provided:

- There are spaces around the value you've provided; are they in the real data? Consider trimming
- Your value has "3" as the month number, which is valid for "M" but not "MM"
- Your vlaue has "4" as the hour number, which is valid for "h" but not "HH" (it's rare to use HH in conjunction with tt)

Leaving the space issue aside, I suspect you want

```
d-M-yyyy h:mm:ss tt
d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
```

as the valid formats.

(See [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) in MSDN for more information.)

Comment: Hi Jon,
I made changes as suggested by you..but still error is there.
:(

Comment: @Ash: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem then - it should be okay. Note that you may want to explicitly specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` rather than using the default culture.

Comment: just curious. I tried: `DateTime strAllocatedOn; string[] format = { "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" }; DateTime.TryParseExact("01/01/2010 01:10:00 PM", format, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out strAllocatedOn);`  and it works